# Does the statement "There is an algorithm that solves ..." make sense?

Tags: logic, algorithms

Let $P(a,b)$ be a class of well-defined problems depending on two parameters.  That is, for each pair $(a,b)$ there is a unique solution to problem $P(a,b)$.  For example, $a,b$ could be integers, and $P(a,b)$ some number theoretic problem, like finding the largest prime factor of $a+b$.

My question is: Does it make sense to state a theorem aking to

Thm. There exists an algorithm that solves $P(a,b)$ in time $O((ab)^2)$.

I would object that there is always an algorithm which solves $P(a,b)$ in constant time. Namely the algorithm "print the unique solution".  I'm asking this question because I found this formulation in a paper on integer programming.  The authors describe an algorithm, and then make this statement.  The proof is "Take our above algorithm".  I was wondering if they should have formulated the theorem differently, like

Thm. Algorithm X solves $P(a,b)$ in time $O((ab)^2)$.

Comment: It would seem that we have finally solved $P = NP$

Comment: That is my point, indeed.  There is an algorithm that prints the correct solution to P ?= NP.  It is either of "print P=NP", or "print P!=NP".  My question is:  Does this make the statement in the first theorem non-sensical, or useless.

Comment: A related discussion is here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126627/existence-of-unknowable-algorithms

Comment: You can't just use "print solution" as your algorithm. There's a precise definition of what algorithms are. Turing machines and so on.

Comment: "Print constant statement" is certainly an algorithm implentable in most models of computation, including Turing machines.  I gave two algorithms for the "P ?= P" problem.  Both of them trivial (just printing some expression indpendent of any input).  One of them is wrong, the other one correct.  Ergo "Thm. There exists a constant time algorithm that prints the correct solution".

Comment: Is $P(a,b)$ assumed to be constant in $a$ and $b$, then?

Comment: For each pair $(a,b)$, $P(a,b)$ is one well-defined problem with a unique solution.

Comment: @Thomas: You need to formalise your computation methods. If you want to have 'print the solution' then you first need a way of putting the solution in your computer's memory, or (if your computer is silly enough to have all possible solutions pre-set in its memory) selecting the right one.

Comment: Their algorithm is probably meant to solve the class $P$, taking $a$ and $b$ as input. It doesn't seem like it would be necessary to reformulate their statement, though, it seems very obvious what is meant

Comment: @CliveNewstead I partially agree about the storing, but I don't agree about the selecting.  The theorem is: "There exists(!) an algorithm" This is so general that you don't need to select the correct algorithm.  Only existence needs to be asserted.  So in case your computer is capable of printing the solution, there also exists an algorihtm that prints the solution.  No statement is made about finding the algorithm, or selecting the correct one among many others.  In this sense you also don't need to store all possible solutions.  You just need to be able to print them.

Comment: @Thomas: I think the conversation has changed from "there exists an algorithm satisfying this given time constraint" to "there exists an algorithm". Given a particular computational model, you can argue without having your hands on an algorithm that *if* an algorithm exists *then* it must take at least [some amount of time] to complete. I'm saying that "print the solution" is not a one-step algorithm when working with any conventional model of computation (say Turing machines), and that it abbreviates a longer algorithm which will, in general, take more time.

Comment: I think the crux of the issue is _uniformity_. Of course there is an algorithm for _each_ $(a, b)$ that solves the problem $P(a, b)$ in $O(1)$; the real problem is, does there exist _one_ algorithm that solves $P(a, b)$ for _all_ $(a, b)$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your difficulty arises from confusing a *problem* with an *instance* of a problem.  The square root problem is: For a given non-negative integer $N$, calculate the largest integer $s$ such that $s^2 \le N$. A particular value of $N$ defines an *instance* of the problem.

Now it is true that for a particular given $N$ there is a constant-time algorithm to solve that *instance* of the problem.  For example, when $N=173$, the algorithm is simply to print `13` on the output tape and halt. But that does not mean that the *problem* can be solved in constant time, because the problem contains many instances. To solve the problem, you have to provide a *single* algorithm to produce the square root for *any* $N$.

Any problem with only a single *instance* is trivial.  As you observe, there is a turing machine which halts and prints the answer in constant time.   Any problem with only a single instance is trivial in this way, including the $P=NP$ problem. Yes, there is a constant-time algorithm to solve the question of whether $P=NP$.  (We just don't know yet what it is.)

However, the problem you describe is not like this.  It has many instances, parameterized by $a$ and $b$.  Any *single* instance is easily solved by a single trivial constant-time algorithm.  But the entire problem isn't because the entire problem requires a solution for given $a$ and $b$.

The trivial algorithms to solve the single instances by printing single numbers don't solve the entire problem because, given $a$ and $b$, you still need to figure out which trivial algorithm is the correct one, and this is decidedly nontrivial—in fact it's the entirety of the problem.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks.  I understood two things now: 1) It's about quantifiers: "There exists an algorithm such that for all instances ..." 2) Any problem with only finitely many instances is 'vulnerable' to the "print the solution" algorithm. (In the Turing machine model with finitely many states)

Comment: "Any problem with only a single instance is trivial" should probably be changed to "Any problem with a constant number of instances is trivial" since the time complexity would be bounded by the time taken for the "worst" instance(which is O(1) since it is fixed).

Answer (score 4):

**Theorem.** Algorithm $X$ described above solves $P(a,b)$ in time $O((ab)^2)$.

**Corollary.** There exists an algorithm $X$ that solves $P(a,b)$ in time $O((ab)^2)$.

**Trivial remark.** For each pair $(a,b)$, there exists an algorithm $X_{a,b}$ that solves $P(a,b)$ in time $O(1)$.